# MySQL keeps crashing

Tags: mysql, crash

MySQL keeps crashing randomly - recent errors in error logs says this

```
160626 21:50:42 [Warning] IP address '113.108.21.*' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160626 22:42:57 [Warning] IP address '124.172.137.*' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
160626 22:43:10 [Warning] IP address '124.172.137.*' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
160626 22:43:25 [Warning] IP address '124.172.137.*' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
160626 22:43:41 [Warning] IP address '124.172.137.*' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
160626 22:43:54 [Warning] IP address '124.172.137.*' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
160626 22:44:09 [Warning] IP address '124.172.137.*' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
160627  0:45:24 [Warning] IP address '117.79.84.*' could not be resolved: Name or service not known

160624  7:00:31 [Warning] IP address '58.221.62.*' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160624  7:05:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160624  7:05:14 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160624  7:05:16 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 16955  user: 'amember'

160624  7:05:16 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 16953  user: 'amember'

160624  7:05:16  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160624  7:05:22  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 195606046122
160624  7:05:22 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160624 07:05:22 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
160624 07:05:23 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

In my.cnf are this lanes, which can resolve this somehow?

```
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

Server have `CPUs` with `20cores` and `258450MB` of RAM

Comment: That's not a crash. You can just ignore the warnings

Comment: No it`s crash because my back-end says "no mysql connection"

Comment: edited my errors

Comment: Rolando's answered this elsewhere: http://serverfault.com/questions/341290/mysql-warning-ip-address-could-not-be-resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```